# How to read txt.file and find sum of different products with different prices

Tags: python, list, sum, txt

**I have a following text-file products.txt:**

Product;Amount;Price
Apple;3;10.00
Banana;1;5.00
Lemon;2;3.00
Orange;4;20.00
Apple;4;8.00

**I want read this file and make a new text-file newfile.txt, which contains value of each row (Amount X Price):**

30.00
5.00
6.00
80.00
32.00

Finally, I want to find the total sum of newfile.txt (which is 30+5+6+80+32 = **153**)

Note, the price of same product can vary and we are not interested total sum of each product.

I started with creating class.

```
class DATA:
    product= ""
    amount= 0
    price= 0
```

def read (name):

```
 list = []
    file= open(name, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    file.readline()
    while (True):
        row= file.readline()
        if(rivi == ''):
            break
        columns= row[:-1].split(';')
        info= DATA()
        info.amount= int(columns[1])
        info.price= int(columns[2])
        info.total = info.amount * info.price
        file.append(info)
    tiedosto.close()
    return list
```

Comment: in your data-file, how rows are separated? by a white-space or it's just a long single line?

Comment: There was a copying typo, each info per item is on its own line and separated with ";".

Comment: ok, edit your question... it is quite a crucial information

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def read(name):
    total = 0

    ori = open(name, 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
    row = ori.readline()

    dest = open("newfile.txt", 'w', encoding="UTF-8")

    row = ori.readline()
    while (row != ""):
        row = row[:-1].split(';')
        res = int(row[1])  * float(row[2])
        total += res
        dest.write(str(res) + "\n")
        row = ori.readline()
    
    ori.close()
    dest.close()
    print(total)

read("products.txt")
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the help. I was able to finish this with the help of answers.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library.

```
import csv

# fix files' paths
path1 = # file to read
path2 = # file to write

# read data and perform computations
rows_tot = [] 
with open(path1, 'r', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        rows_tot.append(float(row['Amount']) * float(row['Price']))

# total sum
print("Total sum:", int(sum(rows_tot)))

# save to file the new data
with open(path2, 'w', newline='') as fd:
    fieldnames = ("AmountXPrice",)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fd, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for value in rows_tot:
        writer.writerow({fieldnames[0]: f"{value:.2f}"})
```

Remark: it is not clear from the question the type of the various data, in case just change `int` with `float` or the other way around.